# Ruby on Rails - Most efficient solution for this Class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, performance, oop, web-applications

I'm a senior Comp. Sci. major working on a senior design project for our faculty. The name of this project is "Gradebook", and it is responsible for allowing instructors to record grades for students and for students to check their grades in a class. This project is written in Ruby on Rails, and this feature set is integrated into our current CS Website.

One requirement for our project is to constantly keep the course average and each of the student's averages updated. So I designed a CourseInfo class and a StudentInfo class to help with this process.

The CourseInfo class accepts a Gradebook (an ActiveRecord object) as a parameter and calculates the course average. It creates an Associative Array of StudentInfo objects, with each StudentInfo object containing the student's overall average in the class. The benefit of this is that I can calculate the Course Average with one line of code that initializes the class, and it is very clean.

But there is one issue that I'm mulling over. The problem is, the CourseInfo object does not survive when another HTTP request is made, I have to keep recreating it. Whether I'm adding an assignment, editing a category, or recording grades, I have to keep it updated because this project uses AJAX requests all the time. Instructors do not have to refresh any pages, because AJAX requests are created with every action.

For example, suppose I'm recording grades for a specific assignment. With each grade I record into the spreadsheet, an AJAX request is made and the course average updates with each new grade. But the problem is, if I want to update the Course Average after recording a student's grade, since the CourseInfo object does not stay alive in the next request, I have to recreate the object to keep the average updated. But that is a LOT of work. That involves calculating each of the student's average for EACH assignment, and then calculating the course average for EACH student. I know, a lot of work and could be simpler right?

So naturally, I want this CourseInfo object to live forever as long as the client is using the website. I've thought of many different ways to solve this problem:

1) **Global Variables or Class Variables** - I honestly want to stay away from this approach because I hear it is bad design. I also hear that this approach is not thread-safe. But it seems to provide a simple solution to my problem?

2) **Serialize the Object in the Database** - This is what I'm learning towards the most. I hear that sometimes people will serialize a Hash that contains user preferences in a web app, why not serialize my CourseInfo object? I've also done some research on the MessagePack gem, and I could potentially encode the CourseInfo object using MessagePack and then store it into the database. I feel like this would be a noticeable performance increase.

3) **Use some kind of cache** - Gems such as Redis act as a cache, and I liked Redis because it is a key value store. I can store a CourseInfo object for each Gradebook that was used during the session, and if I need to update the CourseInfo object, I can simply fetch the CourseInfo object by using the Gradebok's ID as a key. But I'm not sure if this is thread-safe. What if two instructors attempt to update two different grades at the same time? Will there be multiple instances of this CourseInfo object for each client using Gradebook?

4) **Store it in the Session** - Yeah I pretty much crossed this option off my list. I researched this approach, and I hear it is horrible to store a lot of data in the session. I don't want to do this.

What do you think? If I don't want to reinitialize this large object for each request, how can I make it live forever? What is the most efficient solution? What do you think about my design?

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
2) Serialize the Object in the Database

due to agile philosophy of implementing the simplest thing that could possibly work first.

see [Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

The course_average allways reflects the persistent state of the users records. Serializing it is a no braner in ActiveRecord. If you are using postgres , you can even use the native [json store](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json), which you can not only deserialize but also query through. No need for additional complexity to maintain an extra store. This solution has also the benefit of having a persistent counter cache.(no need to recalculate if nothing changes)

However using a cache is also a valuable option. Just remember, if you want to use redis as a cache store you have to explicitly configure a [cache expiring policy](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache), as by default none of the keys will expire and you will recieve an out of memory error, when redis grows beyound the size of RAM on the machine. 
The [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) gem will setup rails to use redis for caching.

Storing this information in the session might also work, but watch out you session not getting to big. The whole session data is allways loaded completely into memory, regardles of some information in it is required or not. Allways loading megabytes of data into memory for every http connection might be not a great idea.

There is also a 5th option, i would evaluate first. Check, does the computation of averages really takes so long. Or can the peformance of it, pobably be improved, e.g. by reducing n+1 queries, setting proper indexes, doing the whole computation in sql or preparing the necessary data completly in sql, so that all the necessary data can be fetched in 1 query.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Everything make sense, but I was wondering if it would be okay if I could post my code so you could take a look at it and tell me if I'm doing it in an efficient way. Or is that more fit for CodeReview? I have worked on it and I feel like I removed the N + 1 queries problem because I eagerly load the ActiveRecord associations within the class.

Comment: @SamParsons If your code works now and you'd like to have it reviewed for improvements, then Code Review is definitely the right site for that. However, make sure you include all the code in your question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help guys. I've accepted your answer dre-hh

Comment: Guess you're right, it's something for codereview. Or if you definitely know, that the code is doing n+1, you could ask, why It happens, then it would fit stackoverflow Format. Either way, feel free to post it, i enjoy solving AR query problemsw

Comment: Plz provide a working project on github, additionally to the code review post. No Ui needed, just some seed data and the sql query.

Comment: Alright I'll have it ready for you later today dre-hh. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the code-review link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80702/ruby-on-rails-computing-overall-averages-in-my-web-application

Comment: As for a working GitHub project, would it be necessary for me to provide that? As it will be complicated to set up the seeds file, and I think you should be able to determine if I'm processing the data in an efficient way by looking at the CodeReview post.

Comment: @SamParsons The Github is completely at your option. As long as the code you want reviewed is in the question, that should be good.